# Auto cell height with iOS autolayout constraints does not work on first time load

Tags: uitableview, autolayout, ios8.3, row-height

I have installed constraints on my table view cells but when I run it on the device it shows me default 44height rows and label text and image view cut within 44 pt height row , but then when I push to another view and come back my cells display fine after coming back.. Why is that happening in the device. I have iPhone 5s with iOS 8.3. I developed this app with Xcode 6.3. Have this code in viewDidLoad.   `self.aTableview.rowHeight=UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.aTableview.estimatedRowHeight=160;`

> 

Update same thing happens in iOS 8.3 simulator also

Comment: Just a random guess: can you try adding this code right before you return the cell from "cellForRowAtIndexPath:"    -     [cell setNeedsLayout];
  [cell layoutIfNeeded];

Comment: or add those above code just after cell initialization.